# Display sObject fields on Picklist onchange

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

**Whenever the name is selected in picklist it should display all the names from account, likewise for industry. Below is my code for vf and controller.**

```
    <apex:page controller="picklistvaluedisplay1">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="call" action="{!showMethod}" rerender="out"/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectValue}" size="1" onchange="call()">
       <apex:selectOption itemlabel="------select---------" itemvalue="------select---------"></apex:selectOption>
       <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Display only Name" itemvalue="Display only Name"></apex:selectOption>
       <apex:selectOption itemlabel="Display only Industry" itemvalue="Display only Industry"></apex:selectOption>

    </apex:selectList>

   <apex:dataTable id="out" value="{!displaySelectedValue}" var="dis"></apex:dataTable>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller:

```
public class picklistvaluedisplay1 {

public List<Account> displaySelectedValue;

public String selectValue;


public void showMethod() {

    if(selectValue == 'Display only Name')
    {
        displaySelectedValue = [select name from Account];
    }
    else if(selectValue == 'Display only Industry')
    {
        displaySelectedValue = [select industry from Account];
    }

}
```

}

I am new to vf. I dont know i did correctly or not. Help me to do this.

My requirement is when Display only Name is selected in picklist it should display names from account object. Similarly for other one also.